# Is there a repository of different implementations of cryptographic algorithms?

Tags: encryption, binary

For my master thesis, I am looking into different implementations of cryptographic algorithms. They should differ in the following aspects:

- Cryptographic Algorithm (AES, DES, RSA, MD5, ...)
- Algorithm Implementation (OpenSSL, MS,  Papers' Reference Implementation, ...)
- Compiler used (VC, GCC, ...)

Also, they should only implement the one algorithm and shouldn't build a GUI or anything else. So, like a commandline:

```
./aes128-brian-gladman-gcc.exe <key> <input>
<output>
```

Do you know of a repository containing the binaries and/or sourcecodes (C/C++)?

Answer (score 1):

- http://www.openssl.org/
- http://code.google.com/p/keyczar/
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/beecrypt/

I don't know that these reference any papers, but the source is all available, and some of them have implementations in various languages.

You can compile openssl with various compilers, etc.

I don't know if this is what you are looking for.

As far as producing one .exe per algorithm, I don't think you are going to find anything that works like that.  Most crypto source is a library, sometimes with front-end drivers.  No doubt you can write a driver per algorithm if you really want to.

Comment: I absolutely agree with your last paragraph.  That will have to be done by @x1lef.  I'm sorely tempted to say no professional cryptographic code would use the command line structure (if only because it probably needs decryption vs encryption indicators), mainly because that exposes the key to passing 'ps' listings (on Unix or Linux).  Plus people are bad at typing long keys by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/) ?